# MySQL-PHP Multiple members and join names to dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of 'members' which looks like the following. In trying to put together a mailing list I found the addresses were easy. The names on the other hand, not so much.

```
| id | firstName | lastName | mbrGrpNum | mbrGrpNumID | dateJoined |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Jane      | Whitmore | 100100    | 01          | 2016-01-01 |
| 2  | Bob       | Whitmore | 100100    | 02          | 2014-02-01 |
| 3  | Carol     | Evans    | 100101    | 01          | 2012-02-01 |
| 4  | Bob       | Roahns   | 100101    | 02          | 2015-09-28 |
| 5  | Corry     | Roahns   | 100101    | 03          | 2014-09-28 |
```

The output I'd like to get is something like this, based on the mbrGrpNum;

```
1 Whitmore, Jane (01/16) & Bob (02/14)
2 Evans, Carol (02/12) & Rohns, Bob (09/15) & Corry (09/14)
```

There could be up to six individuals with the same `mbrGrpNum` (essentially the members of a household) all with different `mbrGrpNumID`'s.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CONCAT` to concatenate columns in a row, and `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate all those in a group.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(lastName, ', ', firstName, ' (',
                DATE_FORMAT(dateJoined, '%m/%y'), ')')
        SEPARATOR ' & ') AS members
FROM members
GROUP BY mbrGrpNum
```

To combine members with the same last name, you need to use a subquery to find them.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(lastName, ', ', family_members) SEPARATOR ' & ') AS members
FROM (
    SELECT mbrGrpNum, lastName,
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                CONCAT(firstName, ' (', DATE_FORMAT(dateJoined, '%m/%y'), ')') SEPARATOR ' & ') AS family_members
    FROM members
    GROUP BY mbrGrpNum, lastName) AS families
GROUP BY mbrGrpNum
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfd5e/6)

Comment: I had tried something similar to that but the output contained several null lines between good data, as yours does.

Comment: Take a look at this. I am absolutely dumbfounded on this one:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0509ee/1

Comment: Some of your `dateJoined` values are not valid dates. Dates have to be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. So when it tries to parse the dates so that it can use `DATE_FORMAT()` on them it gets `NULL`, and this makes `CONCAT()` return `NULL` as well.

Comment: For instance, `10-01-1952` should be `1952-10-01`.

Comment: It would be best if you used a `DATE` datatype instead of a string for this column.

Comment: Just saw that. Time to correct the crappy storage engine too. LOL Thank you so much Barmar. :) I've been pulling my hair out with this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

@barmar Is it possible to join the entire contents of a table (i.e. 'addresses') the "combined members" concat (second one listed above) to get the output of the concatenation with the address info?